# The onQueryTextSubmit in SearchView is processed twice in Android Java

Tags: java, android, searchview

Why the `onQueryTextSubmit` method in `SearchView` is processed twice?
I need one result, how can I do it?

This is my code:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (query != null)
                audioRequest(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following code to prevent `onQueryTextSubmit` from getting executed twice:

`searchView.clearFocus();`

Comment: Where to call this ?

Comment: Right before the return statement in the overwritten `onQueryTextSubmit()`

Answer (score 8):

It generates two outputs when entered from the keyboard on the emulator but it creates single output when clicked on the search button on the keypad of the emulator. So, I think you should not worry about this. On all mobile phones or tablets, this error might not going to happen.

But, searchView.clearFocus(); also works here.

Answer (score 2):

`SearchView` has the following `OnEditorActionListener` on Android API 28:

```
private final OnEditorActionListener mOnEditorActionListener = new OnEditorActionListener() {

    /**
     * Called when the input method default action key is pressed.
     */
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        onSubmitQuery();
        return true;
    }
};
```

And in my debugger, I see that `onEditorAction` is called with both `KeyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and then `KeyEvent.action == ACTION_UP`.

This seems like a bug in `SearchView`.

Answer (score -1):

Just a shot. Since you're handling the search by yourself, try returning true instead of false.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (query != null)
        audioRequest(query);
    return true;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html

Answer (score -1):

**Want to search more than 1 word?**

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {return  false; }

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            final ArrayList<DictObjectModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < wordcombimelist.size(); i++) {

                final String text = wordcombimelist.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(newText)) {

                    filteredList.add(new DictObjectModel(wordcombimelist.get(i),meancombimelist.get(i)));
                }
            }
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

try to call your method after the text changed like this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText != null)
                audioRequest(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

For everyone who is struggling with the same issue, here's what the documentation says about the `onQueryTextSubmit(String query)` method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextSubmit(java.lang.String)) :

> The listener can override the standard behavior by returning true to
>   indicate that it has handled the submit request.

So simply replace `return false` by `return true` :

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (query != null)
        audioRequest(query);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing `return true`, and I still see this behavior.

Comment: Good concept, but doesn't fix if already true. As mentioned above, likely a bug specific to emulator.