# Android SearchView usage example

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to implement `SearchView` in my android app to open an `Activity` and perform a search task in that activity. For some reason, the activity that `SearchView` opens gets paused after starting, causing it's `onCreate` method to be called twice which in turn performs the search twice. Obviously not optimal since this means hitting the backend twice for every request.

I can't figure out why this is happening, so I start to belive this is intended behavior. Can anyone provide a small know working example project that uses `SearchView`? I looked everywhere for a working example to see if this is indeed the intended behavior, but I had no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your code

Comment: I opened this thread for the issue with my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756974/android-fragment-oncreate-called-twice

Comment: On this thread I am just trying to find a working example project